# Git-Rebase: Failed on patch deleting a file that got already modified

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I try to rebase my branch to catch up with master. But Git fails with the given problem:

> ...
>   warning: squelched 41 whitespace errors
>   warning: 46 lines add whitespace errors.
>   Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
>   CONFLICT (modify/delete): project/package/XXX.java deleted in CommitName and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of project/package/XXX.java left in tree.

It seams that in the branch I deleted a file within a patch and that file got modified on master as well. When I now try to rebase the branch to origin/master, the merge process does not know what to do with the patch since the file I delete has changed now and the patch can not further applied.

What is the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a merge conflict like such occurs, you'll notice that you are still in process of `rebase`. In order to continue, those files need to be staged. You can stage the change with either `git rm` or `git add`. Then you have to continue the rebase with `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: You are correct. I did not noticed that the rebase is basically replaying each patch against the current project tree. But what I noticed that rebase seams to be buggy. I saw merge notations not being done correctly and I even screwed up an entire rebase process since at the last step it removed the rebase-apply directory but git status still reported an ongoing rebase process. So I had to delete and clone the repo again.